# tidyverse problems when loading tidyverse in .Rprofile

Tags: r, tidyverse

I recently tried experimenting with .Rprofile files.
In my project I am always working with the tidyverse package so I thought I would create an .Rprofile file in the project's main directory which loads the library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

The library is indeed loaded when I open the project but I it is not runnig as usual.

This code gives an error:

```
tibble(a = 1:5) %>% filter(a > 4)
```

> Error in filter(., a > 4) : object 'a' not found

I assume that I have to include something in .Rprofile but I couldn't find out what it was.

Comment: Please check the packages loaded as I am not able to reproduce the issue

Comment: It is nearly always a bad idea to load packages in your .Rprofile since that ties your software to your particular configuration.

Comment: @akrun: package is loaded: I get the tidyverse loading screen on the console and also the `tibble` function works fine.

@G.Grothendieck is there any other way to load a package every time I work on a project?

Comment: Is `tidyverse` the only package you have in your `.Rprofile`?

Comment: @PoGibas: yes it is. The only line I use in `.Rprofile`is `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: You need to load the default packages before `tidyverse`. With your solution, you load `tidyverse` before and so the `filter` function, if not specified, comes from the `stats` package. Even if very ugly, insert `invisible(lapply(.Options$defaultPackages, function(x) library(x, character.only=TRUE)))` before `library(tidyverse)` in your `.Rprofile`.

Comment: I also want to stress what @G.Grothendieck said: don't load packages in your profile. It's a very bad practice and make your code less portable.

Comment: Thank you, 
your solution works fine. 
Also I found `options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "tidyverse"))`.
But, I will take your advises and not lot the package in .Rprofile.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `dplyr::filter`? There is a filter function by default in R, so you need to specify that is the dplyr's filter.  Try with `tibble(a = 1:5) %>% dplyr::filter(a > 4)`

Comment: This seems to work, although I don't understand why: 
this line is working without problems:
`tibble(a = 1:5) %>% filter_at(vars("a"), any_vars(. > 4))`

My guess is that `tidyverse` is loaded before the `stats` package which causes R to look for `stats::filter` first.

Comment: That's because `filter_at` is a inner function of the dplyr so It will not create conflicts. Open your RStudio and load the tidyverse, you will the conflicts between functions/packages. I recommend you to use the `library::` when using filter, select, etc., because they are masked in multiple packages (stats, dplyr, data.table, etc.)